# Can't change material color, diffuse doesn't do anything

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to give a part of a blender model a wooden texture, however, the diffuse option stays white in the preview/renderer even though in the color bar under the "Diffuse" section of the properties displays the brown color I want.

I followed a tutorial on making just a cube have the texture, and that seems to work fine. I do the same thing to the part, even meticulously going through and making sure all the options are the same, but the color still doesn't change.

Further, another part doesn't seem to render the same color as in the preview, even though, with that part, the preview is exactly what I want.

I imported the model from a Solidworks assembly as a .wrl and re-saved as .blend. Not sure if that screws with it. Any help appreciated!

[image: Blender Pics that hopefully help]

Comment: um... I think when you took your screenshot, you took it of all three monitors

Comment: the view you are showing us is solid view, it displays the object color, not the material. Use MAJ + Z and see if your diffuse color appears.

Comment: That was intentional, to show the model I'm trying to fix in the middle and my test cube on the right. What is MAJ?

Comment: I think he meant `Alt+Z`

Comment: Ah, thanks Duarte. I'll try and get back when I can (it was on a school pc that I got kicked off of)

Comment: Did you UV unwrap it?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm basically a super-noob at this... lol. As for the Alt+z thing, it turned the whole thing in the editor window very shiny white but didn't appear to change the render at all.